# download option is not showing by selecting all library files in sharepoint

Tags: sharepoint-online

in SharePoint library files download option is not showing when selecting all files
if I select single file it is showing download option
if I select all files and I uncheck the first file  it will show the download option
what wrong with first item?
I need to display the download option when selecting the all files

limit is not problem
I unblocked all items also

Answer (score 0):

the Download File button disappears when you select multiple files, this is designed by SharePoint, and we can't change it.
If you want to download all the files,

1. you can [download all files from a document library using PowerShell](https://www.sharepointdiary.com/2017/03/sharepoint-online-download-all-files-from-document-library-using-powershell.html#:%7E:text=To%20download%20all%20files%20from%20a%20SharePoint%20Online,library.%20Similarly%2C%20you%20can%20download%20folders%20as%20well.)
2. you can [view files in File Explorer](https://www.sharepointdiary.com/2022/06/sharepoint-online-configure-view-in-file-explorer-in-edge.html) and copy all the files.
3. you can [sync your files to your computer](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/sync-sharepoint-files-and-folders-87a96948-4dd7-43e4-aca1-53f3e18bea9b).